# Unable to refresh the router menu in Angular 4

Tags: angular, router

I'm unable to have the router menu update itself when doing a `router.navigateByUrl` in `Angular 4`.

What I'm doing is really basic, I'm just trying to hide the login/logout menu when the user isn't/is authenticated. Below is my `app.component.html`:

```
<h1>
  {{ appName }}
</h1>

<nav>
    <a *ngIf="!isLogged" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    <a *ngIf="isLogged" routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And here is my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    isLogged: boolean;

    // inject auth
    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isLogged = this.auth.isLogged;
        console.log('[app] islogged:' + this.auth.isLogged);

        // redirect according to whether user logged in
        if (this.isLogged)
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/total');
        else
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
}
```

As you can tell, `Login` and `Logout` are two separate components. To show which part of the code is responsible for this issue, below is the `LogoutComponent::ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // logout
    this.auth.logout();

    // redirect to /login
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
}
```

The last command is able to redirect to the `/` but the menu isn't updated according to the template posted in the first code.

**Edit:**
This is the service used to login/logout users:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    isLogged: boolean = false;
    token: string;

    constructor() { }

    login(token: string) {
        // save token on login
        this.isLogged = true;
        this.token = token;
    }

    logout() {
        // delete token on logout
        this.isLogged = false;
        this.token = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: With a console log, when you logout, do you really get isLogged=false?

Comment: @Wandrille Yes I've tried it and it's set to False.

Comment: the console log on the ngInit of your app.component.html give false? Or on your service?

Comment: Yes if I put it after the `this.auth.logout()`.

Comment: If you put manualy this.isLogged=false, is it working?

Comment: @Wandrille The problem isn't because of that instruction because the console.log shows that the value of the boolean variable is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it based on the route as,

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

While the above will solve your navigation issue.In addition to that, the actual problem lies with the way you update **`isLogged`** variable in your `app.component.html`

According to the way you have right now, it wont get updated whenever it is updated in other components. So you should have the **`shared service`** with a variable **`subject`**, which would watch for changes.

Something like this,

```
export class AppMessageQueuService {
    authenticatedUserData: Subject<LoginInfo>;
    constructor() {
        this.authenticatedUserData = new Subject<LoginInfo>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, the menu is still not updated. Also the parameter should be a string not an array.

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/login']) is the correct way to use .navigate()

Comment: I meant that when the user is authenticated, he can see the 'Login` menu. But once authenticated and redirected to another page, now he should see the `Logout` link instead. Same thing when a user logout (the menu needs to change as well).

Comment: @h4k1m it depends on the variable isLogged! where do you assign?

Comment: @Wandrille You're right, my bad, but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Inside the `this.auth.logout()` you see above, the `isLogged` variable is set to false, and it's set to true in the login component. The app component (main) just fetches its value.

Comment: those two are two different components i guess! how you are sure that variable gets updateD?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm saving that boolean variable in the `LocalStorage` so it's accessbile by all the components.

Comment: @h4k1m Thats where the problem is! LocalStorage does not watch for changes

Comment: @Sajeetharan Is there another place to store it so that I can have access to it from these components?

Comment: you need to use a service with variable of type subject

Comment: go for a [shared service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or in the new component in ngonInit take the value from local storage

Comment: @h4k1m yeah! but this should answer your question!

Comment: @Sajeetharan By variable of type object do you mean that the `isLogged` variable should appear as a class member in the service?

Comment: @h4k1mc yes exactly

Comment: @Sajeetharan This class variable wouldn't be persistant in this case. It doesn't seem to solve the problem either (I replaced all the calls to LocalStorage with a class variable, but the menu doesn't get updated either).

Comment: @Sajeetharan I've updated my code using a Subject object inside the service class and it's working well. Could you update your response so I can accept it?

Comment: @h4k1m updated the answer, please accept and upvote! thanks